# Navigating to sub router outlet in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have following routes structure

```
{
    path: 'reports',
    component: ReportTypeSelectorComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'infrastructure',
        component: InfrastructureComponent,
        outlet: 'report',
        children: [
          { path: '', component: Duplicate, outlet: 'infrastructure' },
          { path: 'static', component: Static, outlet: 'infrastructure' },
          { path: 'change', component: Change, outlet: 'infrastructure' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

As you can see I have named router outlet "report" with nested named router outlet "infrastructure", when I browsing to **/reports/(report:infrastructure)** loaded component Duplicate that is expected behavior. But how can I navigate to Static or Change component? I cannot figure it out. For example **/reports/(report:infrastructure)/(infrastructure:static)** not works.

Comment: `reports/(report:infrastructure)/static` ?

Comment: @KevinFONTAINE no, I tried it not work

Comment: `reports/(report:infrastructure/static)` ?

Comment: @KevinFONTAINE same result, also tried reports/(report:infrastructure/infrastructure:static) and several other combinations

Comment: @KevinFONTAINE I replaced named routed outlet with regular router outlet in nested child, now it works with (report:infrastructure/static)